# react-spring and react-intersection-observer - tons of rerenders

Tags: reactjs, react-spring, react-intersection-observer

[JSFiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-stallman-shbsy?file=/src/App.js)

Code:

```
export default function App() {
  const spring = useSpring({ from: { opacity: 0 }, to: { opacity: 1 } });

  const [ref] = useInView();

  rerenders++;
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "200vh" }}>
      <div style={{ height: "150vh" }}></div>
      <animated.div
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          height: "50px",
          width: "50px",
          backgroundColor: "red",
          opacity: spring.opacity
        }}
      >
        Hello!
      </animated.div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Attaching `useInView`'s `ref` (a hook from `react-intersection-observer`) causes constant rerendering of the component. Why is that so?

Using an IntersectionObserver yourself does not do such a thing:

```
  const ref = useRef<any>();
  
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const obs = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
      entries.forEach((entry, index) => {
        console.log(entry);
      });
    });
    obs.observe(ref.current);
  }, []);
```

Comment: I'm having same issue. Would be great if your shared your solution if you found one in the meantime.

Comment: @Hans write your own useIntersectionObserver, that one is broken